# Convert week to month by getting their last date of month in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have a weekly time series data and converted to monthly series, but the problem here is I need to combine this data with other data which is also a monthly but it has with their last date of month

```
state_id  county_id  dt          sales1     sales2
    1        AWD     2018-01-06   50.1       43.4
    1        AWD     2018-01-13   42.0       74.4
    1        AWD     2018-01-20   21.0       32.1
    1        AWD     2018-01-27   40.2       40.25




library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
final_monthly <- final %>%
  group_by(month = round_date(dt, "monthly"), state_id,county_id) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(starts_with('sales')), mean)
```

Desired output

```
state_id   county_id    dt          sales1    sales2
    1         AWD      2018-01-31    38.325    47.53
```

Here the date is last values of month but my code gives me the first date of month. I would like to get the last day of month

Comment: Perhaps `ceiling_date`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `as.yearmon` from `zoo`. Try out

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(zoo)
final %>%
        group_by(dt = as.Date(as.yearmon(dt), frac = 1), state_id,county_id) %>%
        summarise_at(vars(starts_with('sales')), mean) %>%
        select(colnames(final))
# output
# A tibble: 1 x 5
# Groups:   dt, state_id [1]
  state_id county_id         dt sales1  sales2
     <int>     <chr>     <date>  <dbl>   <dbl>
1        1       AWD 2018-01-31 38.325 47.5375
```

The tip here is that `as.yearmon(final$dt)` gives a month vector `[1] "janv. 2018" "janv. 2018" "janv. 2018" "janv. 2018"`